# Is there any way to audit SSIS total data transfer size?

Tags: ssis, audit

I'm trying to audit a SSIS package.  Getting the execution duration is pretty simple: just use a script task at the start and at the end to log the current datetime.  But I'd also like to know how much data it's shoving down my network connection, and I can't find any good way to do that.

I can see that there are performance counters for data transfer/second, but what I'm looking for is a total: "when all is said and done, how many bytes of data did this package ship across the network?"  Is there any way to answer that question?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a built in audit telling you that.  You can run a separate task and select count from each data transfer before the transfer (or after) and save that off.  Or have one step get all the counts if you have multiple data flows, and save that of somewhere.

Comment: @Brad How do I go from "select count from each table" to "number of bytes transferred over the network"?  My goal here is to get some sort of ballpark idea of what this will cost to run in a cloud environment, where you're charged for data transfer by volume.

Comment: FWIW, the PackageStart/PackageEnd events are fired and will show you those times. Depending on whether you're executing via the SSISDB or classic package model, those can be automatically collected. Network bandwidth ... Let me think on that one. You can guesstimate it out by looking at the shape of the buffers but there are exceptions to the rule, like Lookup or OLE DB Command